# How to run a php function after certain time without using cron

Tags: php

I have a block of code and want to run it after certain time intervals, say after every 3 seconds. If I get required result it should die otherwise another request will be sent after 3 seconds. Any idea to do it with php.

Thanks in advance for any help

Comment: If you get more than 1 hit every 3 seconds, you could do it when a visitor hits your site, but this is very dodgy. You really do need to use `cron`.

Comment: but i have to pass some parameters to the function according to users request.

Comment: Any reason you dont wanna use cron? Only alternative is to have your users poll the server every 3 seconds via javascript and keep a check on last update but that would involve wasted resources.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can sleep in a loop:

```
while (true) {
    $result = doSomething;
    if (resultIsGood) {
        break;
    }
    sleep(3);
}
```

If you don't want to keep the browser waiting, you can look up `ignore_user_abort()` solutions on Google.

Answer (score 1):

If what you want to execute MySQL queries (and nothing else), maybe using the MySQL event scheduler could fit your need:
http://dev.mysql.md/doc/refman/5.5/en/events-overview.html